# I need excel to look for dates in column A 14 days before the date in my calendar if there's a F in the next column add the product name to calendar

Tags: date, excel-formula, feature-lookups

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oDsBf.png)

I have tried a VLOOKUP, Index and Match, =if I think it may be a combination of them I just need pointing in the right direction. I have attached the image of my spreadsheet. The aim is that the calendar can populate its self as I will be adding data daily.

Comment: Can you provide context to your screenshot? For example, what are your inputs, what are your ouputs? I see #N/A, what is this supposed to be? You need to provide more information for the community to assist with your question.